# Password Generator With User Given Length

Tags: c#, passwords, console-application, password-generator

I need to write a password generator which generates a password that has min. 2 lower case letters, min. 2 upper case letters, min. 1 digit and min. 1 special character.It also has to be a user given length.
How do I give a password a minimum length using this code. For ex: 10?

This is what I'v been suffering with but I have tried to limit the length without any success, so I just removed those codes:

```
class Program
{

    private const string Capital = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUP";
    private const string Lower = "abcdefghijklmnoup";
    private const string Digit = "1234567890";
    private const string Spec = "@&#><-[]Łł$ß";
    private const string AllChars = Capital + Lower + Digit + Spec;
    private static Random r = new Random();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            char capitalLetter = GenerateChar(Capital);
            InsertAtRandomPos(password, capitalLetter);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            char lowerLetter = GenerateChar(Lower);
            InsertAtRandomPos(password, lowerLetter);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            char digit = GenerateChar(Digit);
            InsertAtRandomPos(password, digit);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            char specialLetter = GenerateChar(Spec);
            InsertAtRandomPos(password, specialLetter);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("A jelszava: {0}",password);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void InsertAtRandomPos(StringBuilder password, char character)
    {
        int randomPosition = r.Next(password.Length + 1);
        password.Insert(randomPosition, character);
    }
    private static char GenerateChar(string availableChars)
    {
        int randomIndex = r.Next(availableChars.Length);
        char randomChar = availableChars[randomIndex];
        return randomChar;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: and the question is ...

Comment: How do I give a password a minimum length using this code. For ex: 10?

Comment: I see, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that might help you:

```cs
static readonly Random r = new Random();

public static string GeneratePassword(
    int length,
    bool useLowercase,
    bool useUppercase,
    bool useDigits,
    bool useSpecialChars,
    string userDefined = null,
    int[] skipCodes = null,
    bool distinct = false
    )
{
    if (!useLowercase && 
        !useUppercase && 
        !useDigits && 
        !useSpecialChars && 
        userDefined is null)
        return "";

    var codes = new List<int>();
    var ri = 0;
    var code = 0;

    while (codes.Count < length)
    {
        code = 0;
        ri = r.Next(0, 5); //get a random option.

        switch (ri)
        {
            case 0 when useLowercase:
                code = r.Next(97, 123);
                break;
            case 1 when useDigits:
                code = r.Next(48, 58);
                break;
            case 2 when useUppercase:
                code = r.Next(65, 91);
                break;
            case 3 when useSpecialChars:
                switch(r.Next(0, 4))
                {
                    case 0:
                        code = r.Next(33, 48);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        code = r.Next(58, 65);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        code = r.Next(91, 96);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        code = r.Next(123, 126);
                        break;
                }
                if (skipCodes != null && skipCodes.Contains(code))
                    code = 0;
                    break;
            case 4 when userDefined != null:
                code = Convert.ToChar(userDefined
                    .Substring(r.Next(0, userDefined.Length), 1));
                break;
        }
        if ((distinct && codes.Contains(code)) || code == 0)
            continue;

        codes.Add(code);
    }
    return string.Join("", codes.Select(c => (char)c));
}
```

Then you can generate a password as follows:

```cs
var userDefined = "-#_$";
//The chars that you don't want to be included like white spaces commas..etc.
int[] skipCodes = new[] { 32, 39, 44, 96, 124 };
var pass = GeneratePassword(12, true, true, true, false, userDefined, skipCodes, true);

Console.WriteLine(pass);
```

Or call it several times to generate a specific pattern. Tweak it to meet your needs.